# OAuth Facebook Login doesn't work

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I'm trying to develop a web app using Google App Engine.
The language i'm using is Python and i'm using the facebook-sdk (https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
I'm stuck at making the OAuth Facebook login works correctly.
Every single time I attempt to log in to my app using Facebook login i get the error

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

You can see the screenshot of the error (in the original language) below

[image: Redirect error]

That are the settings of my Facebook app

[image: Facebook login settings]

[image: Facebook login settings2]

That's the code of my app's RequestHandler which handle the login's requests

```
import facebook
import os
import webapp2
import urllib
from webapp2_extras import sessions


facebook_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
facebook_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
facebook_graphUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8'
facebook_redirectUri = 'http://gold-circlet-160109.appspot.com/login/'
facebook_requestCode = 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?' + 
urllib.urlencode(
                    {'client_id':facebook_ID,
                     'redirect_uri':facebook_redirectUri,
                     'scope':'public_profile, email, user_friends'})


def retrieve_access_token(code):    
   args = {'redirect_uri': facebook_redirectUri,
        'client_id': facebook_ID,
        'client_secret': facebook_secret,
        'code': code}
   access_token = urllib.urlopen(facebook_graphUrl + "/oauth/access_token?" + urllib.urlencode(args)).read()
   access_token = urlparse.parse_qs(access_token)
   return access_token['access_token'][0]

def get_graph_api(token):
   if isinstance(token, dict):
        return facebook.GraphAPI(token['access_token'])
   else:
        return facebook.GraphAPI(token)

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def dispatch(self):
       self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
       try:
           webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
       finally:
           self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

   @webapp2.cached_property
   def session(self):
       return self.session_store.get_session()

class FBLogin(BaseHandler):
def get(self):
    code = self.request.get('code')
    if self.request.get("code"):
        access_tk = retrieve_access_token(code)
        facebookObject = get_graph_api(access_tk)
        facebookObject = facebookObject.get_object('me')
        self.session["ECommerceUser"] = dict(
                        idSocial = facebookObject['id'],
                        image='http://graph.facebook.com/'+facebookObject['id']+'/picture?type=square',
                        username=last_name[0] + " " + last_name[1],
                        loginMethod=loginMethod
                        )
        self.redirect("/")
    else:
        self.redirect(facebook_requestCode)
```

I set the same redirect URI in the URL login request is set in the Facebook Login settings, as you can see from the code above (i followed this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow)

Any suggestion?

Comment: _“I set the same redirect URI in the URL login request is set in the Facebook Login settings”_ – no, you didn’t. You are using `http://gold-circlet-160109.appspot.com/login/` in your code, but you specified `https://gold-circlet-160109.appspot.com/login/` in your app settings.

Comment: Thank you! I was too focused on the other part of the URL that i forgot to check if I typed http or https.
Such a silly error